Why did Kenny go to Heaven?
In South Park, it is firmly established that the correct religion is

 Mormonism

and that only members of this religion go to Heaven.
In South Park: Bigger, Longer, & Uncut's ending,

 Kenny dies and goes to Heaven

despite not being a member of this religion.
Why?

The official audio commentary with Trey and Matt just says "Yeah, he [Kenny] gets to go to heaven". No help there.

Isn’t it a demon who claims “the correct answer was ‘Mormon’”? If I’m remembering that right, then it’s reasonable to suppose the demon is not telling the whole truth. Of course we later see that everyone in heaven shows stereotypical Mormon dress and behavior, but none of that clarifies that only Mormons go to heaven.

From the movie wikipedia page:

As per a bet with Cartman, Kenny sets his fart on fire, imitating a scene from the film, accidentally immolates himself and is rushed to the hospital, where he dies from a botched heart transplant. Kenny is denied entry to Heaven and descends into Hell, wherein he encounters Satan and his abusive partner Saddam Hussein.

Then, at the end:

Grateful for Kenny's support, Satan grants him one wish. Kenny wishes for everything to return to a pre-war state and parts with his friends before disappearing. [...] For his sacrifice, Kenny is allowed entry into Heaven.

Amongst Catholics and Mormons (and others), there are many discussions about whether non-believers or believers of others religions can achieve salvation and go to Heaven. Some say yes, some say no. So, according to certain, it is possible but always through the grace obtained by Christ. As part of the South Park show, and their subversive way of dealing and juggling with ideas and all, no wonder Kenny gets his salvation from Satan though :) it's just another funny subversive twist...
